# Mapping template arguments of one function template to template arguments of another (c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

How do I apply a complicated function to a template argument of one function template, so that it can be used as a template argument in another function template? I am new to templates, so please bear with me.

In the code below I call `foo<1,2>()`, this generates a function, and inside the body of that function, it calls a generated `bar<2>()` function. The problem for me is that I have a complicated function that, as far as I know, cannot be evaluated with the standard arithmetic operators.

I can use c++11, if it helps.

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t c>
unsigned int bar(){
    return c;
}

template<size_t a, size_t b>
unsigned int foo(){
    return bar<a*b>();
    //return bar<COMPLICATEDFUNCTION(a,b)>();   // what I actually want to do
}

int main(void) {

    std::cout << foo<1,2>();
    return 0;
}
```

If it helps, my specific function is f(r,c) = r*c - c - (c choose 2) which counts the number of lower-diagonal elements of a nonsquare matrix (r > c). The function I wrote to compute this could be declared `inline`, but as I understand it, the compiler does not promise this. In a previous question, I asked about using macro functions, and that was met with skepticism. Also, in that same thread, constexpr functions were suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `constexpr` is your savior.  Using the following definitions:

```
constexpr size_t fact(size_t x) {
  return (x == 0 || x == 1) ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);
}

constexpr size_t choose(size_t n, size_t k) {
  return fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n - k));
}

constexpr size_t complexfunc(size_t r, size_t c) {
  return r * c - c - choose(c, 2);
}
```

calling `bar<complexfunc(a,b)>();` should just work, assuming C++11.

Comment: just wanted to point out that this will complain with certain edge cases like if k > n. My current, non-`constexpr` implementation doesn't work with all the if statements. But thanks for pointing these out to me

Comment: Yes.  That is a limitation in C++11 that was removed in C++14.  Your if-statement based version would work just fine there, most likely, with just `constexpr` added.